# Static routing in Linux (as a router)

Tags: routing, static-routes

Currently I have a physical Linux machine (Centos7) with two physical interfaces. On the eth0 interface I have 3 virtual interfaces - eth0.66, eth0,67, eth0.99 (vlan interfaces). wlan0 is the internal WAN uplink. tun0 is created through an SSL Site-to-Site tunnel. I have enabled ipv4 forwarding in the kernel.

As of currently, the default routing tables looks like this:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth0.66
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth0.67
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 eth0.99
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     192.168.60.65   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.6.0     192.168.60.65   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.7.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.7.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0.99
192.168.7.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0.66
192.168.7.224  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0.67
```

I am trying to force all traffic from the 192.168.7.224/27 network through the tunnel and use 192.168.7.1 as the default gateway (192.168.7.1 is the GW of the firewall on the server side for the VPN, which I also control).

I've tried to make a new routing table (in etc/iproute2/rt_tables) - and adding the appropriate rules (for now in the runtime and not via a script, but I know how to do this for persistent routing).

```
from all to 192.168.7.224/27 lookup custom
from 192.168.7.224/27 lookup custom
```

and then the routing table:

```
default via 192.168.7.1 dev tun0
```

at which point, everything breaks... ping stops working, internet on the eth0.67 network fails, etc. How can I get this routing correctly? Probably a stupid question, but does the kernel routing table get completely ignored and do I need to write in all the other routes the SSL VPN is pushing? (the 192.168.2.0 and 6.0 routes are coming from the SSL OPENVPN config).

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: One more route was needed 192.168.7.224/27 dev eth0.67 src 0.0.0.0 table custom.

Other routes still persist, so no need to double add them. (things for the 192.168.6.0 and 192.168.2.0 networks).

PS- thanks for the downvotes!